# Does it going to be asynchronous

Tags: .net, rest, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I currently have a question about async/await in REST api with dotnet core. I m working on an api that needs to make some http call with the GetAsync method from HttpClient. Here is how it works :

This my get method into my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string url, string aid)
    {
        try
        {
            //...

            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await _htmlService.HtmlLinkCheck(aid, cancellationTokenSource.Token, correctUrl), cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            ConnectionsHelper.RegisterTask(aid, task, cancellationTokenSource);
            ConnectionsHelper.UpRequest(aid);

            return Ok("Ok");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return this.InternalServerError(exception);
        }
    }
```

this method is calling a service which is injected and configured in the startup file like this :

```
services.AddScoped<IRequestService, RequestService>();
        services.AddScoped<IHtmlCheckService, HtmlCheckService>();
```

into that HtmlCheckService into the HtmlLinkCheck i'm calling the requestService to make the call :

```
private async Task CheckHtmlLink(CancellationToken token)
    {
            //...

            var result = await _requestService.GetRequest(handledUrl.url);
```

and the GetRequest method do :

```
public async Task<string> GetRequest(Uri url)
    {
        // ...

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
```

_httpClient is a static variable (used by all the different instance of RequestService) :

```
private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    public RequestService()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
        {
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                             DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        }

        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0");

    }
```

If my i m make let s say 100 requests to my REST API, does for each request the calls to GetAsync are going to be thread safe (not one call at a time, but calls in parallel ) between each request (instances of RequestService because of AddScope method to create the injection) ? It looks like if it works in parallel but how can i be sure of it ?

Would it be more effective to create a new instance of httpClient per instance of RequestService ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClient` is designed to allow multiple simultaneous requests.

It does not allow you to change *properties* like `BaseAddress` or `DefaultRequestHeaders` once it has been used; if you need different properties set for different requests, then you should use a different `HttpClient` instance for those requests.

But in the general case, yes, you should use one `HttpClient` instance for every request that shares its property values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No i don't need to change properties for each request. So if i understand you correctly, my implementation is correct ?

Comment: @FlawinneJulien: Yes.

Comment: Or you could use `SendAsync()` and specify the headers etc. on the `HttpRequestMessage` right?

Comment: yes i was also wondering if it s ok to re-instanciate my static variable each time a requestService is instanciate (because i do a new HttpClient into my constructor ... ).

Comment: a if(_httpClient == null { var handler ... shoud do the stuff. But apparently you say that my code is running async between request :) and that was my initial question

Comment: @FlawinneJulien: I did not catch that. Your `RequestService` constructor should be `static`.